# SKSpriteNode doesn't run Action after changing parent

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

after testing almost everything, i hope that someone of you got an idea.

It's a complex app, so i hope i get all relevant parts:

I want to "page" through `SKNode`'s, containing some `SKSpriteNodes`. 
After paging,the childnodes don't react on `runAction:`.

**The Paging**:
To page, i use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

The current "page" = `SKNode *currentForegroundNode`.
The next "page"    = `SKNode *nextForegroundNode`.

in `(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {..}` i'm moving the current & next page. (working)

in `(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {...}`

```
SKAction *moveNextForegroundToFront = [SKAction moveToX:0 duration:0.2f];
        [self.nextForegroundNode runAction:moveNextForegroundToFront completion:^{

[self.currentForegroundNode removeAllChildren];
[self.nextForegroundNode enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"node_1" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
//Node is kind of class SKSpriteNode
       [node removeFromParent];
       [self.currentForegroundNode addChild:node];
       }
    }];
    [self.nextForegroundNode removeAllChildren];
    [self.nextForegroundNode removeFromParent];
    self.nextForegroundNode = nil;
}
```

After this, everything look's good. BUT i can't run any Actions on the child-nodes of self.currentForegroundNode with iOS7! With iOS8 installed, it works fine as expected.

Comment: Where do you assign self.currentForegroundNode after moving the new node in place? Also note that removeAllChildren is superfluous if followed by removeFromParent. And consider that removing a node, then readding it may stop or remove any actions this node was running, so perhaps change runAction so that it runs the actions after the node has changed parents.

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast! both ForegroundNodes are instantiated in a lazy getter.
There are no actions on the „node_1“-nodes before changing the parentNode. I also tried removeAllActions before changing parent without an effect.